# how to insert data into file with ',' as a delimiter

Tags: unix, sed, awk

```
cat try_1.txt | grep 'aa|' | cut -d '|' -f 2 >> abc.txt
```

Using the above I am selecting few fiends and putting it into abc.txt

Data of abc.txt is

```
aa
bb
ccc
dd
```

I want data inserted into abc.txt like : expected output :

```
aa,bb,ccc,dd
```

Comment: Grep accepts a filename. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: I want it in one line. It is coming one by one in one column. I want aa,bb,cc,dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paste -s -d, - < try_1.txt
```

does exactly what you seem to want, but I do not at all understand why you have the `grep 'aa|'`, so I probably don't know what you want.

Ah, now I think I understand what you want:

```
awk '/aa\|/ {print $2}' FS=\| try_1.txt | paste -s -d, - >> abc.txt
```

Comment: Thanks William for solution.

Answer (score 0):

No need for multiple tools and pipes, just use awk":

```
$ cat try_1.txt
aa|aa
aa|bb
aa|ccc
aa|dd

$ awk -F'|' '/aa\|/{printf "%s%s",s,$2;s=","} END{print ""}' try_1.txt
aa,bb,ccc,dd
```